# Tiff versus BigTiff

Tags: tiff

Please let me know if there is another Stack Exchange community this question would be better suited for.

I am trying to understand the basic differences between Tiff and BigTiff. I have looked on various sites and the only difference that is mentioned is that BigTiff uses 64-bit offsets while Tiff uses 32-bit offsets. That being said, you would need to know which of the two types you are reading. How is this done? According to https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/main/api/tifffmt.html, this is done by reading a file flag. However, the flag they are referring to appears to be unique to their own reader as I cannot find a corresponding data field in the specifications as shown by http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/egff.htm. What am I missing? Does BigTiff use a different file header than Tiff?

Comment: See http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/bigtiff.html

Comment: You're right about the page you found in our documentation; it is indeed specific to LEADTOOLS and not meant to be a guide about the BigTIFF format itself. Our SDK does not directly give you access to the bits and bytes of TIFF and BigTIFF headers, because it aims at simplifying handling image formats and their sub-types (hundreds of them). If you want to use the SDK's free evaluation to compare your findings to our implementation, feel free to [download it from our website](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything you need to know is described in [the BigTIFF link](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/bigtiff.html) posted by @cgohlke, but to provide an answer, here's a quick summary:

**Yes, it uses a different file header.**

Normal **TIFF** uses the following header:

- 2 byte byte order mark, "II" for "Intel"/little endian, or "MM" for "Motorola"/big endian.
- The (version) number 42* as a 16 bit value, in the endianness given.
- Unsigned 32 bit offset to IFD0

**BigTIFF** uses a slightly different header:

- 2 byte byte order mark as above
- The (version) number 43 as a 16 bit value, in the endianness given.
- Byte size of offset as a 16 bit value, always 8 for BigTIFF
- 2 byte padding, always 0 for BigTIFF
- Unsigned 64 bit offset to IFD0

---

*) The value 42 was chosen for its *"deep philosophical significance"*. Or according to the official specification, *"[a]n arbitrary but carefully chosen number"*...