# Error trying to read a region from a very large image file in java

Tags: java, javax.imageio, twelvemonkeys

I need to read a very large image file (56000 px X 49000 px). I need to read it in small rectangular chunks, so I am trying to follow this example: [Read region from very large image file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466513/read-region-from-very-large-image-file-in-java)

However, I get this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width*height > Integer.MAX_VALUE!

My code snippet is below (taken more or less exactly from the link above):

```
ImageInputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File(this.inFile)); // File or input stream
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CreateTrainingSetFromImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);

    ImageReader r = readers.next();
    System.out.println("Using reader: " + r);
    r.setInput(stream);
    try {
        System.out.println("Height = " + r.getHeight(0));
        System.out.println("Width = " + r.getWidth(0));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CreateTrainingSetFromImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

ImageReadParam param = r.getDefaultReadParam();
Rectangle sourceRegion = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200);
param.setSourceRegion(sourceRegion); // Set region

        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = r.read(0, param); // Will read only the region specified
            System.out.println("Read file " + this.inFile);
            System.out.println("Width = " + image.getWidth());
            System.out.println("Height = " + image.getHeight());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CreateTrainingSetFromImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

My understanding is that specifying the Rectangle sourceRegion for param would make the ImageReader read only that small chunk of the image, so I don't understand what's causing the error. Any help would be much appreciated. If it helps, I am using the TwelveMonkeys ImageIO plugins.

Here is the output:

```
Using reader: com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader@5437dd04
Height = 49429
Width = 56281
Apr 23, 2017 11:57:17 AM createtrainingsetfromimage.CreateTrainingSetFromImage    test
SEVERE: null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width*height > Integer.MAX_VALUE!
at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(ImageReader.java:2840)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1066)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:1034)
at com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:382)
at createtrainingsetfromimage.CreateTrainingSetFromImage.test(CreateTrainingSetFromImage.java:102)
at createtrainingsetfromimage.CreateTrainingSetFromImage.createTrainingSet(CreateTrainingSetFromImage.java:168)
at createtrainingsetfromimage.CreateTrainingSetFromImage.main(CreateTrainingSetFromImage.java:46)
```

Comment: where does the exception occur?

Comment: I am not sure what is the source of the error , but it suggest that you need to use double.

Comment: Provide a stacktrace, please, and indicate on which line the error is occuring. I'm going to guess `ImageIO.createImageInputStream` does a calculation with the width and height which exceeds the max integer size.

Comment: The error occurs at image = r.read(0, param); I've edited the post to include the output.

Comment: @Samarth Are you able to post a link to such a huge image, for test purposes?

Comment: @haraldK Here is a link to the jpeg I am using for test purposes: http://www.filedropper.com/floydclass

Comment: @haraldK Hmm... I just tried it again (in both Firefox and Chrome) and was able to download it. Let me try to find another file hosting service to share it.

Comment: @Samarth Never mind, probably just an issue with the work network. Works fine now from a different location.

Answer (score 0):

There's a known bug/limitation in the `getDestination` method of the `ImageReader` base class (the super class of the `JPEGImageReader` and all other ImageIO reader implementations), that calculates the width * height of the *input image*, rather than the region you are actually trying to read... This prevents you from reading even small parts of such images.

The code looks like this, and the `width` and `height` parameters are the dimensions of the input:

```
if ((long) width * height > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("width*height > Integer.MAX_VALUE!");
}
```

In most of my (the TwelveMonkeys ImageIO library's) `ImageReader`s I work around this limitation by using a different implementation of the `getDestination` method. But for the `JPEGImageReader` I delegate the actual decoding to the `com.sun....JPEGImageReader`, which uses the original method, and causes this exception.

It might be possible to work around the problem by using the `readRaster` method instead of `read` (as it does not use the `getDestination` method), but it requires extra work, and I haven't had the possibility to test this yet.

Comment: I am using a jpeg for testing (I posted the link in response to your comments above). I actually need to use it with tiff files. When I tried the same code with a tiff, I got the following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException` at the line `ImageReader r = readers.next();`. Prior to that I check to make sure that the TwelveMonkeys `TIFFImageReader` is registered as a tiff reader, so that is not the problem. Does this indicate my tiff image is non-compliant somehow?

Comment: If you are 100% sure the `TIFFImageReader` is registered, then that indicates that your file isn't a TIFF file (the logic for detecting is quite simple, inspecting only the first 4 bytes). Perhaps it's a BigTIFF?

Comment: I think it may have been generated from arcGIS, so it might be a geotiff.

Comment: Here's a link to the tiff file if you want to try it: http://www.filedropper.com/floydclass_1

Comment: @Samarth As I thought, the file is a [BigTIFF](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43376951/1428606). The TwelveMonkeys `TIFFImageReader` does not support BigTIFF currently. It might in the future, though. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I wouldn't have figured it out on my own.

Comment: @Samarth FYI: I'm planning to add [support for BigTIFF](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues/342) in the next version of the library.